# Advice on installing laravel without compromising the current website installation?

Tags: php, wordpress, laravel-5, web, cpanel

I'm going to install laravel onto a cpanel server- I'll use it for the admin access dashboard; the server already has a website online- that will lead to the aforementioned admin panel- built using wordpress.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put all of Laravel into your `public_html` folder and create sub folder `/admin/` or something.

Then go and create subdomain `admin.examlple.com` and set it's docroot to `public_html/admin/public`

This way you don't modify any of your `public_html` stuff, where I guess your main site lies in